# Change session after succesfull logon to Azure AD with OAuth2

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, session-cookies

During Azure OAuth2 authentication we need to store the access_token to get a access_token. This session has to be shared between our host and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` (and no one else) so the cookie same site is set to `lax`. After authentication it would make sense to set this back to strict again for obvious reasons. Is there a way to change a cookies samesite strict again.

Is this possible? Or is there another way to handle the session or session cookie?